# highlight scrolling text on iphone

Tags: iphone, uitextview, calayer, cgcontext

i'm in troubled show lyrics .i use uitextview show lyrics code snips

```
IBOutlet UILabel *lrcshow;
IBOutlet UITextView *showlrc;

self.lrcshow.text = [lrcDictss objectForKey:
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)self.player.currentTime]];
if (self.lrcshow.text!=nil) {
    NSRange selection = [self.showlrc.text rangeOfString:self.lrcshow.text]; 
    if( selection.location != NSNotFound ){
        showlrc.selectedRange = selection; 
   }
}
```

lyrics line by line scrolling show,the problem is now playing(selectedRange) lyric is not highlight, i want this line highlight how can i code ? any suggestion？or use calayer 、cgcontext quartz core instead it? how can I do it ?

ps.for me english is difficult I want to achieve smooth scrolling effect lyrics show

lyrics style show pic url :

this is my app style:  http://www.flickr.com/photos/53054715@N05/5360345226/

this is good style : flickr.com/photos/53054715@N05/5359722887/

Comment: I understand that English is not your first language. That said, **please** put some effort into making your question comprehensible. Also, what is "lr" and "lrc?" "Lyric?"

Comment: [ti:My Heart Will Go On]
  [ar:Celine Dion]
  [al:Grammy1999]
  [by:thwei] 
  [00:00.00]《My Heart Will Go On》
  [00:01.00]from Titanic
  [00:03.00]
  [00:06.00]Sung By "Celine Dion"
  [00:09.00]
  [00:20.00]Every night in my dreams

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you mean... you want to highlight a text and selectedRange is not working right?

If so then read this:

selectedRange only works when the keyboard is showing. In your lyrics app you don't want that right? 
So you will need at least a CALayer to make it look like is selected. 
Also you need the coordinates of the text and that is no a simple task.

If your text is static (the font, size, frame width never changes) then you could have coordinates of the text in your dictionary, so you can resize your CALayer accordingly

Hope it helps.
GoodLuck

Comment: Thank you for your answer，any other method instead of selectedRange because is not flatness

Comment: what do you mean by flatness?

Comment: “selectedRange” is one line jump to the slected line ,not one line Slowly rolling to slected line